# Validate length of parameter in POST operation (Azure API Management)

Tags: post, openapi, jsonschema, azure-api-management

I have created an API on Azure API Management with this operation:

```
POST https://example.azure-api.net/product/check
content-type: application/json
{
    "productId":"a77swsa2"
}
```

`productId` is a string that cannot have more than 8 characters. How can I protect the API on Azure APIM so that I reject all requests that include a `productId` of more than 8 characters? Now I see it is possible to paste huge strings and it is all sent to the backend.

Comment: OpenAPI supports [`maxLength`](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#string) for strings. Does Azure APIM support `maxLength` validation? If not, you'll have to validate the length in the backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in two ways:

1. Manually using `choose` policy and `context.Request.Body.As<Jobject>()` to parse request body as `JObject` and then inspect `"productId"` to check its length and if it's larger than 8 characters use `return-response` policy to fail the request.
2. If your API's schema is correct, you can make use of `validate-content` policy.

Comment: Seems that option 2 doesn't work. At least using an inbound policy like this:

`<validate-content unspecified-content-type-action="prevent" max-size="1024" size-exceeded-action="prevent" errors-variable-name="requestBodyValidation">
            <content type="application/json" validate-as="json" action="prevent" />
        </validate-content>`

Comment: I can't say for sure without looking at your configuration, but second option depends on API and parameter having correct schema